# What is the good practice to terminate program in catch clause

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a method throws an Exception

```
public int myMethod throws Exception
```

I have another function calls myMethod function and hava try-catch block.
I throws a runtime exception to enforce the program to be terminated.
Is this a proper way to terminate the program? If I do this way, it prints the stack trace twice and the stack trace from RuntimeException is useless.

What is the suggested way to terminate program in catch clause with printing the full stack trace.

```
public int callMyMethod(){
     try{
         myMethod();
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
          throw new RuntimeException();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

If this code is part of the application itself then calling `System.exit(int)` is possibly the best option.  (But if the application is "failing", then you should call `exit` with a non-zero return code.  Zero conventionally means "succeeded".)

However, if there is a significant possibility that this code is going to be embedded / reused in a larger Java application, calling `System.exit(...)` is problematic.  For instance a library that calls `System.exit(...)` when something bad happens is going to cause havoc for an application that uses it.

For something like that, you might throw a custom runtime exception which you catch and handle specifically in your `main` method.  (If I was doing that, I'd pass the `Exception` as a constructor parameter to the custom exception ... and make it the `cause` exception.  And I wouldn't print it / log it at that point.)

(Calling `System.exit(...)` also causes problems when you are unit testing ... 'cos the call will most likely pull the plug on the JVM running the test suite!)

---

The other point is that `catch (Exception ...)` is almost always a BAD IDEA.  The point is that this catches just about everything (including all sorts of things that you never dreamed could happen!) and buries them.  It is far better to catch the specific exceptions you are expecting (e.g. checked exceptions) and can deal with ... and just let the rest propagate in the normal way.

If you are stuck with `catch (Exception ...)` because you are using something that is declared as throwing `Exception`, the best way to deal with it is to change the `throws Exception`.  And the sooner the better.  Change the `throws Exception` to declare a list of (more) specific exceptions that you expect to be thrown by the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int callMyMethod(){
     try{
         myMethod();
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
          System.exit(0); // terminates with exit code 0, no extra stack trace.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is one of the most important aspects in programming.
The answer for your question depends on what type of application you are working on.

system.exit(0) will just terminate your program and this can create a lot of havoc .
Also make sure that you never catch Exception , if you are doing that then you are catching all the types of exceptions which you may not intend to handle also.

Always catch Specific exception such that it gives you opportunity to handle it in a manner which you need.